# Разделение формы на разные экраны

Tags: jquery

Задача.

У меня есть довольно разухабистая форма, дизайн которой я хочу улучшить. В ней есть списки чекбоксов, списки радиокнопок, каждый из которых может быть довольно большим (10+ элементов).
Я хочу вынести редактирование этих списков на отдельный экран. Как, например, в этом примере:

```
<div id="home"><ul class="rounded">
    <li class="arrow">
        <a href="#checkboxes">Checkboxes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow">
        <a href="#radiobuttons">Radiobuttons</a>
    </li>
</ul></div>
<div id="checkboxes"><ul class="rounded edit">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" title="checkbox 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" title="checkbox 2" />
    </li>
</ul></div>
<div id="radiobuttons"><ul class="rounded edit">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="1" title="radiobutton 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="2" title="radiobutton 2" />
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

Проблема:
я не могу объединить эти div-ы в одну форму. jQTouch берет элементы первого уровня для представления на одном экране. Если я помещу все div-ы в form, они все будут видимы. То есть я могу редактировать форму, но не могу послать ее на сервер целиком. Как решить эту проблему?

http://pastebin.com/wSsZYxyh — полный исходник примера, смотреть в Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел подходящее решение: оставить все как есть, но перед отправкой формы копировать все нужные мне div-ы в невидимую часть часть формы.

То есть:

1) Создаем невидимый див в конце формы:

```
<div id="hiddenInputsPlaceholder" style='display: none'></div>
```

2) Обработчик отправки выглядит так:

```
$("#hiddenInputsPlaceholder").empty();
$("#checkboxes ul").clone().appendTo('#hiddenInputsPlaceholder');
$("#radiobuttons ul").clone().appendTo('#hiddenInputsPlaceholder');
$("#home").submit();
```

Полный исходник здесь: http://pastebin.com/UEBgC89Z

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте вкладки. Сыровато, на быструю руку, переключение лучше обернуть в функции, но примерно так:

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="background-color:gray;">
    <tr>
        <td 
            id="td0" 
            style="border: 2px solid white;" 
            onclick="javascript:tab0.style.display='block'; tab1.style.display='none';">show tab0</td>
        <td 
            id="td1" 
            style="border: 2px solid white;" 
            onclick="javascript:tab0.style.display='none'; tab1.style.display='block';">show tab1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="tab0">this is tab0 content<br />
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:td1.onclick()" value="next">
</div>
<div id="tab1" style="display:none;">this is tab1 content<br />
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:td0.onclick()" value="back" />
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('submit')" value="go" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это немного не то, хотелось бы воспользоваться плавными iPhone-like переходами между этими экранами, которые в jQTouch достаются "нахаляву".